# Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error: SQLite Error when trying to create a view

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax-error

I am attempting to create a view in SQLite but apparently there is a syntax error, I'm not sure what it is. This is the query:

```
CREATE VIEW personDetails(fname, lname, bdate, bplace, carsowned,ticketsRcvd) AS
SELECT p.fname,p.lname,p.bdate,p.bplace,COUNT(DISTINCT(r.vin)),COUNT(DISTINCT(t.violation))
FROM persons p LEFT JOIN registrations r ON p.fname = r.fname
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON r.regno = t.regno
GROUP BY p.fname,p.lname, p.bdate,p.bplace;
```

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT r.vin), COUNT(DISTINCT t.violation)`, without embedded parentheses.

Comment: why the registration is joined based on firstname? `LEFT JOIN registrations r ON p.fname = r.fname`

Comment: @GMB Sorry that's not it, I don't even know what could be wrong

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Because that's the only thing I could join it by, there was also a last name but I'm not sure how to specify join based on two elements

Comment: actually, nothing's wrong on your view, my suspicion is maybe your using wrong columns.

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ yea that could be it, although before adding the CREATE VIEW, the SELECT statement was working fine :/

Comment: have you tried `COUNT(DISTINCT(coalesce(r.vin, 0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more of a comment then an answer, but formatting doesn't really lend itself to a comment.

I would try this:

```
CREATE VIEW personDetails
AS
SELECT p.fname, p.lname, p.bdate, p.bplace,
   COUNT(DISTINCT r.vin) carsowned, COUNT(DISTINCT t.violation) ticketsRcvd
FROM persons p
LEFT JOIN registrations r
   ON p.fname = r.fname
   AND p.lname = r.lname
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON r.regno = t.regno
GROUP BY p.fname, p.lname, p.bdate, p.bplace;
```

Comment: @c3688014, seems your sqlite version is 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong your view creation. But its best practice to drop view first exists before creating new one.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [personDetails]; 
CREATE VIEW [personDetails](fname, lname, bdate, bplace, carsowned,ticketsRcvd) AS
SELECT p.fname,p.lname,p.bdate,p.bplace,COUNT(DISTINCT(coalesce(r.vin, 0))),COUNT(DISTINCT(coalesce(t.violation, 0)))
FROM persons p 
LEFT JOIN registrations r ON p.fname = r.fname
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON r.regno = t.regno
GROUP BY p.fname,p.lname, p.bdate,p.bplace;
```

Comment: Still not working, I don't think it's syntax related or the drop view. I'll see if I can use other columns, thanks for the help though